# grep find lines which have "$" only once

Tags: unix, grep

I have a file whose contents are

```
$VARIABLE1 text $VARIABLE2
text $VARIBLE2
$VARIABLE3 TEXT $VARIABLE2
anothertext $VARIBLE2
```

$VARIABLE2 appears in all lines

I need all the lines that has only $VARIABLE2
so i need the lines where $ exists only once

I tried

```
cat filename | grep  -F "$\{1\}"
```

It doesnt give me any output

Comment: And what happened? It's like you stopped abruptly half way through your explanation.

Comment: Sorry about that, it doesnt give me any output.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Pretty sure $ needs to be escaped at the very least. Otherwise it means EOL.

Comment: @MadPhysicist he has `-F`

Comment: @Kent. Good call, but then what is the point of \{1\}? You're either in literal mode or in regex mode, but not some weird superposition of both.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that I cannot explain. but `$` in his codes is literal `$`, escaping is not required.

Comment: @Kent. Yup. Other issues abound, but that one he did escape :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```
grep '^[^$]*\$[^$]*$' filename
```

Explained: A line starting with any number of "not dollar" characters, then a dollar, then any number of "not dollar" characters until end.

This ensures you only capture lines with **exactly one** dollar sign. Note the use of single quotes to prevent bash from expanding the dollar sign.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the lines with single `$` sign:

```
awk -F'$' 'NF==2' file
```

this awk one-liner will help you.

What it does is: make the `$` as the field separator, if there is one and only one `$` in a line, the line must be separated into 2 parts (fields).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using two commands in a pipeline - one to remove lines with no `$` and one to remove those with 2 or more `$`:

```
grep -F '$' filename | grep -v '\$.*\$'
```

P.S. No need to invoke `cat` - `grep` will happily accept a filename, or you can redirect its input using `<`.